# pop middle element in C

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

1. So i was doing my assignment when i got stuck in this question. We are using stack [struct]  in C and want to pop middle element of the stack, i wrote the common push and pop function, with print and isEmpty functions. i just need some help with question.
2. We need to pop middle element from the list.
3. Example of desired input and out given below

   ```
   Input:  Stack[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   Output: Stack[] = [1, 2, 4, 5]

   Input: Stack[] = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   Output: Stack[] = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
   ```
4. and my code is here

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   //self-referenced structure
   struct stackNode {
       int data;
       struct startNode *nextPtr;
   };
   typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
   typedef StackNode StackNodePtr;

   //prototypes
   void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info);
   int pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr);
   void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr);
   void isEmpty(StackNodePtr *topPtr);
   int main(void){
       StackNodePtr stackPtr = NULL;
       int count= 0;
       char value;
       char input;
       printf("%s","Stack[] = [");
       scanf("%s\n", input );

       while(input != "]"){
           scanf("%c, ",&value);
           count++;
           push(&stackPtr, value);
       }
       if(count%2==0){
           count = count / 2;
       }
       else {
           ++count;
           count = count / 2;
       }
       puts("\n");
       printf("Stack[] = ");
       printStack()
   }

   void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr,int info){
       StackNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));

       if (newPtr != NULL){
           newPtr->data = info;
           newPtr->nextPtr = *topPtr;
           *topPtr = newPtr;
       }
       else {
           printf("%d not inserted, no memory\n", info);
       }
   }
   int pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr){
       StackNodePtr tempPtr = *topPtr;
       int popValue = (*topPtr)->data;
       *topPtr =(*topPtr)->nextPtr;
       return popValue;
   }
   void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr){
       if(currentPtr == NULL) {
           puts("The stack is empty\n");
       } else {
           printf("%s","[");
           while(currentPtr != NULL) {
               printf("%d, ",currentPtr->data );
               currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
           }
           printf("%s","]");
       }
   }

   void isEmpty(StackNodePtr topPtr){
       return topPtr == NULL;
   }
   ```
5. EDIT:

   ```
   //Author: Shivam taneja

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   //self-referenced structure
   struct stackNode {
       int data;
       struct stackNode *nextPtr;
   };
   typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
   typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;

   //prototypes
   void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info);
   int pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int iter);
   void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr);
   int main(void){
       StackNodePtr stackPtr = NULL;
       int count = 0;
       char value;
       printf("%s","Stack[] = [");
       scanf("%c, ", &value);
       while(!(value == ']')) {
           printf()
           scanf("%c",&value);
           count++;
           push(&stackPtr, value);
       }
       if(count%2==0){
           count = count / 2;
       }
       else {
           ++count;
           count = count / 2;
       }
       puts("\n");
       pop(&stackPtr, count);
       printf("Stack[] = ");
       printStack(stackPtr);
   }

   void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr,int info){
       StackNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));

       if (newPtr != NULL){
           newPtr->data = info;
           newPtr->nextPtr = *topPtr;
           *topPtr = newPtr;
       }
       else {
           printf("%d not inserted, no memory\n", info);
       }
   }
   int pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int iter){
       StackNodePtr tempPtr = *topPtr;
       while(iter != 0){
           iter--;
           *topPtr =(*topPtr)->nextPtr;
       }
       int popValue = (*topPtr)->data;
       return popValue;
   }
   void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr){
       if(currentPtr == NULL) {
           puts("The stack is empty\n");
       } else {
           printf("%s","[");
           while(currentPtr != NULL) {
               printf("%d, ",currentPtr->data );
               currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
           }
           printf("%s","]");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a list, you'll have to do it differently than with array, but here's how you do it with an array:

`[0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ? | ...]`

Let's say you want to pop element 1.

You then keep the address of current stack pointer, move to one you want to pop, pop it, then shift all elements to the front, and move pointer back to previous pointer - 1.

Result:

`[0 | 2 | 3 | ? | ...]`

You need to do exactly the same, but with your list.

Your stack looks like this:

`0->1->2->3->?`

You want to pop 1, what you do is go to node `1`, pop it, then move all elements to the front:

`0->2->3->?`.

Let's see what happens if you simply delete `1`:
`0->? 2->3->?`

The list gets cut off, you need to rejoin it.

To rejoin it, you need to know `previous` node and `next` node, then, it's as easy as `previous.next = next`.

Since we can't simply peek back, you need to keep track of previous node when iterating over the list, so, find the desired element while keeping track of previous node, then simply rewire the connection from `previous.next = current`, to `previous.next = current.next`, you can then return the value of current.

Comment: i am not using a list, the whole code aint working the way i thought it would work like. my idea was to use scanf to get the numbers and each number shall be taken from the string and push to the stack and then count will do its work and pop the middle one